# How to plot an image using debug mode in Canopy

Tags: canopy, ipdb

I'm newbie in Canopy and I don't really know why I can't show images or figures when I'm using ipdb inside the Canopy editor. However, if I use the same code in the ipdb launched directly from console the figures and images show up. For example, if I use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(I)
plt.show()
```

the image show up in ipdb launched from console, but in Canopy (ipdb) the image doesn't show up, however, the image is showing up only when the debug process is finished.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Could you be more specific about the exact steps that you are taking, and at what step you expect to see the image but don't? Also, what version of Canopy are you using? 1.5.5 is the current release, and 1.6.1 is due in one week.

Comment: Hi, this ilustrate my problem: A) launch canopy (1.5.5) open the editor and debug a particular code.  In the the ipdb console inside the canopy editor I run this code, plt.figure() and plt.imshow(I), but  no image is showed. However, B) if I run the ipython from a terminal and goes to the debug mode (run -b <code.py>) I can show the images using the same code described before (plt.figure(), plt.imshow(I)). Note: in A the figures are only showing when the debugger stop. I tried to use plt.ion() in the ipdb but it is the same.